# How to clone HDD to SSD and fix all potential performance issues

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, clone

I want to clone my existing HDD with Win7 to a brand new SSD, ideally using `dd` on a live Ubuntu CD. The SSD is bigger, so no problems shrinking. The HDD has two partitions.

My partition start offset on my HDD is 32256 bytes (31.5 KiB), which is supposed to mean that the partition as is, is not aligned properly for the SSD. (right?)

Question 1. After cloning, will simply moving the partition or shrinking "from the front" in GParted, to an offset which is a multiple of 4 KiB fix the problem? Is this all there is to it? I need to do this for both partitions, correct?

Edit: Moving a bootable partition with Windows 7 is not a good idea. Won't work out of the box, but may be fixable with a recovery disk.

Question 2. My HDD sector size is 512 and my NTFS cluster size is 4KiB. Will this be just fine on the SSD after cloning? (I have no clue what my SSD reports for its sector size, but I guess it doesn't even matter for an SSD)

Edit: Apparently, this is just fine. Will put up an answer if I manage to do everything I intended.

Comment: Clone partitions, not drives.

Comment: It may not have been obvious: I have a Windows 7 installation on one of the HDD partitions which is bootable. Simply cloning that partition and `dd`ing it back to a different disk with a precreated parition table, and potentially a slightly different location definitely won't work. Trial and error has shown that simply moving it after `dd`ing the whole disk doesn't work without some fixing either.